# Sum for cells with X colour and another sum for cell with Y colour / numbers on the same line

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to know which formula to use to make several sums
On a same line : one sum for cells with red background and another one for cells with green background.

Can you help me?

Comment: Would you like to achieve this using Formula in sheet directly or using Apps script? Please explain a little more and post some information on what did you try to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using Apps script, check the code:

```
function addbackgrounds()
{
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = book.getRange(15, 1 , 1, book.getLastColumn());
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var cellValues = range_input.getValues();
  var colorX = "#ffe599";
  var colorY = "#990000";
  var sumX = 0;
  var sumY = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i< cell_colors[0].length; i++)
  {
    if( cell_colors[0][i] == colorX ){sumX = sumX + cellValues[0][i]; }
    else if( cell_colors[0][i] == colorY ){sumY = sumY + cellValues[0][i]; }
  }
  Logger.log(sumX);
  Logger.log(sumY);

 }
```

Hope this helps!